# Passing nested parameters to an ajax get request

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In a Rails 5.1 app (without jQuery) how can I pass nested params via a GET ajax request?

I have the following

```
Rails.ajax({
  url: select.getAttribute('data-url') + "?xxx",
  type: "GET"
});
```

If I replace `xxx` with, for instance, `pippo=pluto`, in my controller

```
params[:name] #=> "pluto"
```

However, in my controller, I need to be able to access a nested param as below.

```
params[:user][:name] #=> "pluto"
```

It seems a simple problem but I cannot find a solution.

Here my JS

```
  document.addEventListener('turbolinks:load', function() {
    var select = document.querySelector("select[name='user[name]']")
    if(select.options[select.selectedIndex].value) {

      Rails.ajax({
        url: select.getAttribute('data-url'),
        type: "GET",
        data: {
          user: {
            name: select.options[select.selectedIndex].value
          }
       }
      });
    }
  });
```

Which produces (user[:name] is always selected)

```
{"object Object"=>nil, "controller"=>"steps", "action"=>"index"} permitted: false>
```

The query string works fine (but is ugly)

```
Rails.ajax({
        url: select.getAttribute('data-url') + '?user[name]=' + select.options[select.selectedIndex].value,
        type: "GET"
      });
```

SIDE QUESTION: To avoid the ajax request in the first place is there an alternative way to automatically trigger the request of the select below when the page is loaded? Currently, it is triggered only when the selected option changes

```
<%= f.select :user, MyUsers.all,
{ data: { remote: true, url: duplicate_users_path } } %>
```

Comment: have u tried `"users[pippo]=pluto"`

Comment: Ok, so somehow you're getting an object (rather than a value) being passed... which makes me think there's something slightly incorrect about `select.options[select.selectedIndex].value` - what happens when you look at this in the javascript console?

Comment: side answer: use onload attribute of body tag

Answer (score 1):

use data option in ajax (recommended)

```
Rails.ajax({
  url: select.getAttribute('data-url'),
  type: 'GET',
  data: {
    users: {
      pippo: 'pluto',
      pippo2: 'pluto2'
    }
  }
});
```

or query string as array

```
Rails.ajax({
  url: select.getAttribute('data-url') + '?users[pippo]=pluto&users[pippo2]=pluto2',
  type: 'GET'
});
```

Comment: `"object Object"` is really weird... can you post the code you used? (please edit and add it to your question, don't post in comments because code formatting is horrendous)